# Do aliases slow down a shell's start?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, alias, zsh

Sometimes my shell (zsh) takes longer to start than usual (I open the terminal, and it hangs a bit until I can input commands).

I have a few aliases on my *.zshrc* (well, actually they're in a different file that *.zshrc* does a `source` on).

If you make an `alias` with the shell open, it remains valid only through the current session, so I started to wonder if all this `source` and `alias` actually harm the shell's startup performance (I'm assuming it has to go through a lengthy process of running all those commands on start).

If that does happen, wouldn't it just be more effective to have those aliases as shell scripts and put them somewhere in my *PATH*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that your shell has to run those `alias` commands when it starts, but this is unlikely to cause start-up to take noticeably longer, especially since you only have a few aliases.

Comment: But some of them are relatively complex. How about my last question, would making them as individual shell scripts actually help, or is there any downside (besides having more files) that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @user137369: As far as startup is concerned, aliases are *never* complex. They're just mappings from strings to strings. Aliases can do very complex things, of course, but that doesn't happen till you actually run them.